# apt install gccgo-go doesn't install gccgo in Docker image

Tags: apt, docker, golang

### Summary

`apt install gccgo-go` doesn't install `ggcgo` in a Docker image build, but it does when run from an image container.

### Details

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 Docker image that I created to test some simple Go apps I wrote. When I `apt install` the `golang-go` and `gccgo-go` packages while building the image, the build completes without errors. But when I bring up and attach to a  container and try to build my Go apps with `go build -compiler gccgo` I get an error that `gccgo` was not found. When I try `which gccgo`, it returns nothing, i.e., the `gccgo` executable is not installed. When I then run `apt install -y gccgo-go` from within the container, the install completes and I can successfully build and run the apps using the `gccgo` executable.

### Environment

My project is available [here](https://github.com/moebius-rex/primes) on GitHub. The Dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/moebius-rex/primes/blob/main/docker/ubuntu.dockerfile) and the Go source code tree starts [here](https://github.com/moebius-rex/primes/tree/main/src/main/go). I'm running Docker Desktop 3.3.1 on macOS 11.3.1 and I use this sequence to build the Ubuntu image and attach to the container:

1. `docker system prune -a`
2. `docker compose build`
3. `docker compose up -d`
4. `docker compose exec ubuntu bash`

### Other notes

While gathering data for this question, I accidentally installed package `gccgo` instead of `ggcgo-go` while building a Docker image. This actually *did* install the `gccgo` executable in the image was available when I started a container. It even managed to "build" `go/sieve`, but this is a utility package, so it's only verifying that the package is buildable. When I tried to build `go/app2`, the compiler failed because it required go v1.16 (the go installed by `golang-go` is 1.13). Clearly, `golang-go` should only ever be paired with 'gccgo-go`, not` gccgo`. also found a` golang`package but that is also v1.3, not the v1.6 that`gccgo` requires.

### Epilog

Again, in summary, `apt install gccgo-go` doesn't work in the image build but it does work in the image container.

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this question, but it seemed like a good place to start. Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

From packaging point of view - the */usr/bin/gccgo* executable is contained exclusively in `gccgo` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=gccgo).

The `gccgo-go` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gccgo-go) contains only */usr/bin/go* [executable](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gccgo-go/filelist) by itself and it depends on `gccgo-9` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gccgo-9) which [provides](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/gccgo-9/filelist) */usr/bin/gccgo-9* executable. Alternatively `golang-go` package [provides](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=usr%2Fbin%2Fgo) its own */usr/bin/go*.

Comment: I didn't immediately understand what you were saying N0rbert. So I hacked around for a bit and found that `gccgo-go` installs `go`, but it *also* installs `gccgo` and my apps now build successfully with the `-compiler gccgo` flag. I'm going to post a response to my on question that provides more details. Thanks so much for the assist!